# GCS client library NoSuchMethod systemNanoTime

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

when I call createOrReplace,

```
private GcsService gcsService = 
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(file, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
```

I see

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime()J
at com.google.common.base.Ticker$1.read(Ticker.java:60)
at com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.start(Stopwatch.java:114)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:138)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:47)
at com.train.trainercircle.rest.ImageResource.getExercises(ImageResource.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at
```

I looked in the pom file dependency manager in elipse and made sure the version of guava needed by gcs-client library is the compiled.

what gives, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Same here with GAE's mapreduce

Comment: Found a fix for me, see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=719#c1) you probably have a google-collections jar on your classpath as well as Guava. Make sure to remove that.
If using Maven

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.google</groupId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

See also [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)

> Guava is a fully compatible superset of the old Google Collections Library. It also includes years worth of bug fixes, doc fixes, and performance fixes, so we strongly encourage you to use Guava instead of Google Collections.
>
> If your application ever ends up with both google-collect-1.0.jar and guava-r##.jar on the same classpath, simply remove the Google Collections JAR and you should be fine. If you don't remove it, it will either cause terrible problems (if it comes before guava in the classpath) or will never even be seen anyway (if it comes after).